Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Connection cannot be resolved to a type DriverManager cannot be resolved
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

class ConnectionDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl1","system","password");
            System.out.println("Connection Established Successfully");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e);
            }
    }
}

what is the solution to this

If you have a module-info.java file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it via right-clicking on the project folder and choosing Configure) or in module-info.java add the required requires ...; statement.

The module-info requires statement would be requires java.sql; If Eclipse is showing you errors you can't run the code until you fix them.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
